# Writing into a .txt from C

Tags: c++, c

I'm making a program in C++ that should write a variable's (temperature) value into a .txt.

Suppose I want to insert the value of this variable constantly in a file.txt in new rows. This file.txt should look something like this:

- 37.0
- 36.0
- 37.1

WITHOUT a blank newline below the last value (37.1). The file should ends next to the last value, not below, in this example, next to the 1. BUT if there new data to insert in the file, i would like to insert this below (37.1), like this:

- 37.0
- 36.9
- 37.1
- 38.0(New data).

Im made this code, but i dont know how to place the new data in a new row without creating a blank newline below the last value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <"eHealth.h>

int main(){
   while(1){
      float temperature = eHealth.getTemperature();
      FILE *myData;
      myData=fopen("file.txt","a");
      fprintf(myData,"%f",temperature);
      fprintf("%\n");
      fclose(myData);
      }
   return(0);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Put a newline **before** the actual data, except on the first line. Pseudocode: `if (!file.empty) { fprintf(file, "\n"); } fprintf(file, "data");`

Comment: Also, this is C, not C++. Furthermore, just `return 0;`, don't `return(0);`. It's not a function.

Comment: if(*myData != EOF) 
    { 
       fprintf(myData,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(myData,"%f",temperature);

i think this might help... not tested

Comment: With [tag:c++] consider using `ofstream` instead of `FILE*`. You're showing plain [tag:c] code here. Choose an appropriate tag!

Comment: `"%\n"` looks suspicious!! (what's the intended purpose of the `'%'` character here?)

Comment: Youre right guys. I mean C, not C++! Im sorry about this confusion!

Comment: @Bankoner See my updates ...

Comment: The above program will run indefinitely. The while lopp should have a proper termination condition. Moreover, if this is a homework problem please add the "homework" tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're asking for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) your code should look like this:

```
#include <ofstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::ofstream out("file.txt");
    bool firstLine = true;
    while(1) { // consider some reasonable shutdown condition, but simply 
               // killing the process might be sufficient
        float temperature = eHealth.getTemperature();

        if(!firstLine) {
            out << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            firstLine = true;
        }
        out << temperature;
        out.flush();

        // Give other processes a chance to access the CPU, just measure every
        // 5 seconds (or what ever is your preferred rate)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For plain [c](/questions/tagged/c) do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    FILE *out = fopen("file.txt","a");
    if(out == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open 'file.txt'");
        return 1;
    }

    bool firstLine = true;
    while(1) { // consider some reasonable shutdown condition, but simply 
               // killing the process might be sufficient
        float temperature = eHealth.getTemperature();
        if(!firstLine) {
            fprintf(out,"\n");
        }
        else {
            firstLine = true;
        }
        fprintf(out,"%f",temperature);
        fflush(out);

        // Give other processes a chance to access the CPU, just measure every
        // 5 seconds (or what ever is your preferred rate)
        sleep(5);
    }
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

As a hint:
If you're testing your code on a *nix like system, you can simply use the `tail -f file.txt` command, to see if your program does what it should.

Comment: Hey g-makulik! this store the data but is still creating an extra blank newline at the end of the .txt . Im trying to fix it as H2CO3 saids!

Comment: @Bankoner See my updated answer and accept if it fits your desired behavior (which is strangely designed though, since most streamed input oriented programs react on '\n' to get new data from a line).

Comment: Thanks  g-makulik! it also helped! :) Problem Solved!